# How to install ethernet driver on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with working wireless connection?

Tags: 10.04, intel, ethernet, atheros

How do I  install the ethernet driver on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with working wireless connection?

```
goutham@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:5580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:588423 (588.4 KB)  TX bytes:588423 (588.4 KB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:1b:d4:0f:a8:4f  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:a3:c4:fe:7c:1c  
          inet addr:192.168.43.167  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6aa3:c4ff:fefe:7c1c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:86963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:111515707 (111.5 MB)  TX bytes:9272272 (9.2 MB)

goutham@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

goutham@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nn |grep Ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet [1969:2062] (rev c1)
goutham@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You're hit by [bug #927782](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/927782). This is fairly new hardware and Ubuntu will not bring support for this in 10.04. Consider upgrading to 12.04 and then the following:

Try installing compat-wireless backported kernel modules (yes, wireless, don't ask why) by installing the package `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic`:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
```

and reboot.

This package contains updated (backported) drivers (kernel modules) from Linux 3.6 for the 3.2 kernel in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider upgrading the kernel and leaving the OS intact. To do this follow the tutorial [here](http://ashu-geek.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-kernel-37-rc1-and-362-released.html)  This will install the newer 3.6 kernel. I have done this in the past and not had any issues.

There are provisions that I would recommend.

Make a backup of anything important. 
Be sure to read the instruction first, be clear as to how to do it before attempting.
Select the CORRECT architecture 32bit or 64bit and download only those files.* `this is what you are currently running` as it is important not to mix them up.